# Hibernate Delete throwing exception on use of tx.commit()

Tags: hibernate, hibernateexception

I have a POJO which is very plain easy only one Id and I am getting an exception when I am deleting a record, where saving and updating is working fine. If i do not use commit() it does not give exception but if i use it gives.!
Here is the code...

```
public class DeleteCompanyRecords {
public static boolean deleteCompany(String comname){
    Boolean res=false;
    Session session = null;
    String comid=GenCompanyCodeWhenGivenCompanyName.genCompanyCode(comname);
    System.out.println(comid);
    Transaction tx = null;
    try{
        session = SessionCreate.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        tx=(Transaction) session.getTransaction();
        ElitSysCompanyMaster employee = 
                (ElitSysCompanyMaster)session.get(ElitSysCompanyMaster.class, comid); 
        session.delete(employee);res=true;
        session.flush();//tx.commit() also gives exception here.
    }catch (Exception e) {
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
        res=false;

    } finally {
        if (session != null)
            if (session.isOpen()){
                session.close();}
    }
    return res;
}
```

In the above code if i use tx.commit also throws the same exception as well as the if(wasCommitted()) statement. Please guide. I am the only person who is working for this complete project. There is no one else.

The table is a very simple table and does not have any mappings as of now.
Exception is as such.

```
  SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/SecurePass] threw exception [org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started] with root cause
org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.rollback(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:202)
    at classes.deleteclasses.DeleteCompanyRecords.deleteCompany(DeleteCompanyRecords.java:25)
    at org.apache.jsp.DeleteRecords.DeleteCompany_jsp._jspService(DeleteCompany_jsp.java:81)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `begin()` the transaction, so `session.getTransaction().begin()`.

On a side note: the exception you are quoting doesn't arise in the `commit()` or `flush()` but in the `rollback()` from the catch block. You can see that in the stacktrace.

Comment: OOOPS..! How can i forget that..! Thanks